# NumberPicker keyboard style in custom EditText

Tags: android, datetime, keyboard

I have such a question - if you use DateTime widget, its keyboard on editing date value looks like this:

[image]

But when you try to set numeric or date input on custom EditText the resulting keyboard usually looks like this:

[image]

Is there a way to get just numeric Keyboard like the first one on EditText? Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

Add `android:inputType="number"` to your edit text

Comment: Well, I think I have written, that "when you try to set numeric or date input" result is the same to down picture.

Answer (score 0):

Add android:inputType="phone" to your edit text

Comment: Great idea! Do you really think I haven't tried it?
http://s7.image1.org/images/2013/06/07/1/a5170f4a5be6e8b7a5c8f062387d6861.png